# How to sort array and retain the results then assign values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this problem and i can't figure out how to give points to a team who both get the same position. E.g. 3 teams get similar percentage and are on 3rd place position, so each of them get similar points.

- if team is first place they get 10pts.
- if team is 2nd place they get 9pts.
- if team is 3rd place they get 8pts.
- if team is 4th place they get 7pts.
- if team is 5th place they get 6pts.
- if team is 6th place they get 5pts.
- if team is 7th place they get 4pts.
- if team is 8th place they get 3pts.

Supposing i have 8 teams;

```
$team_aScore and $team_cScore = 98%; (first place)
$team_dScore, $team_eScore and $team_fScore = 96%; (3rd place)
$team_bScore = 94%; (5th place)
$team_gScore = 97%; (2nd place)
$team_hScore = 95%; (4th place)
```

What i did was sort the team first with the highest points. I know that team a has an id of 1, team b has an id of 2 and so on...

```
  $array = array(1=>$team_aScore, 2=>$team_bScore, 3=>$team_cScore, 4=>$team_dScore, 5=>$team_eScore, 6=>$team_fScore, 7=>$team_gScore, 8=>$team_hScore);
arsort($array);

$x = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $x++;

  if($x==1) {$givepts = 10;}
  if($x==2) {$givepts = 9;}
  if($x==3) {$givepts = 8;}
  if($x==4) {$givepts = 7;}
  if($x==5) {$givepts = 6;}
  if($x==6) {$givepts = 5;}
  if($x==7) {$givepts = 4;}
  if($x==8) {$givepts = 3;}

  $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teamScore(id,score) VALUES($x,$givepts)");

}
```

The results was this, each team get individual points.

- team_a = 10pts
- team_c = 9pts
- team_g = 8pts
- team_d = 7pts
- team_e = 6pts
- team_f = 5pts
- team_h = 4pts
- team_b = 3pts

That is not what i want. What i want to achieve is this

- team_a = 10pts
- team_c = 10pts
- team_g = 9pts
- team_d = 8pts
- team_e = 8pts
- team_f = 8pts
- team_h = 7pts
- team_b = 6pts

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If not, let us know so we can help more. If so, will you please mark the most helpful answer as "accepted"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've setup the data a little differently so it is easier to work with. I created a `team_score` function that does the sorting and points assignment for your teams. I set an initial assignment points value of `10`. Then, I'm storing the last checked score in a variable and checking the current score against it. If it's the same, I don't decrement the assignment points value.

```
<?php
// Data Setup
$team_tags = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h');
$team_scores = array(98, 98, 97, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94);
shuffle($team_scores);
$teams = array();
foreach ($team_tags as $tag) {
    $teams[$tag] = array_pop($team_scores);
}

// Sort and Score
$team_points = team_score($teams);
var_dump($team_points);
var_dump($teams);

function team_score($teams) {
    // Sort
    arsort($teams);
    // Max Points
    $points = 10;
    $last_score = false;
    // Assign Points
    $team_points = array();
    foreach ($teams as $tag => $score) {
        if ($last_score && $score < $last_score) {
            $points--;
        }
        $team_points[$tag] = $points;
        $last_score = $score;
    }
    return $team_points;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is the percentage is not currently given. So it should have another function to sort  which team gets the highest percentage first or which team has similar percentage so you can then put the values to $team_scores = array($x)

Comment: The function `team_score` is sorting by percentage. In the area under `// Data Setup`. I'm simply setting the data you say you will already have. Also, as mentioned before, I changed the way the data is organized so that it is workable. Both percentages (scores) and points are available in my code above. I am `var_dump`ing both for you to see. Did you run this code in a file alone? Look here to see what I mean: http://runnable.com/VN-pu6t1xdxz2nk_/28513232-for-php